# Event calling before page unload

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pop up a dialog before an `html` page is unloaded asking to unload page or not.  If yes is selected then the unload continues, and if no is selected then the unload event is canceled.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't set the text to "yes"/"no" (it'll be "Ok"/"Cancel" in most browsers), but you can prompt (be careful when using this) when leaving the page in any manner using [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you wish to leave the page?";
}
```

Only use this if you have a good reason, don't annoy your users.  That being said, this will prompt when leaving the page, that includes history back, forward, refresh, closing the window/tab, clicking a link to navigate away or submitting a form, etc.  So you'll probably want to call this when going somewhere that shouldn't prompt:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

For example, submitting a form of information, you'd want to prompt when leaving/losing the data, but not when actually submitting it.

Comment: @suraj: For an example, start typing an answer below and then try to leave the page. :-) StackOverflow does exactly what Nick describes.

Comment: *"So you'll probably want to call this when going somewhere that shouldn't prompt..."* Or use a flag or check in the function, rather than disconnecting it. If the function doesn't return a string, it doesn't prompt the user.

Comment: @TJCrowder - There was *some* issue with this I can't remember for the life of me, but ran into it before, where detaching was always the safe route.  If I think of it today I'll come back and update, I do remember it was a rare edge case though, possibly in just 1 or 2 browsers (there's security, or annoyance, code governing what's allowed to be used in that function in various browsers).