# How do I detect a page refresh using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, refresh, reload

How might I capture the page reload event?

I have a messaging system which loses all its input when the user refreshes the page. I want to use ajax to re-populate, hence my need to detect when the page has been refreshed/reloaded.

Comment: You can find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699357/event-calling-before-page-unload

Answer (score 42):

```
$('body').bind('beforeunload',function(){
   //do something
});
```

But this wont save any info for later, unless you were planning on saving that in a cookie somewhere (or local storage) and the `unload` event does not always fire in all browsers.

---

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qpK7Y/

Code:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){

     //save info somewhere

    return 'are you sure you want to leave?';

});
```

Comment: For the record, it'll be fired on page close too.

Comment: you can also save info from the page using this method. just get all the input filed values,make a datastring and add the window.location.href="pagename?datastring" in the beforeunload function

Comment: Should this be `on` and `unload`? http://api.jquery.com/unload/ -- also, does this detect F5 in Firefox?

Comment: This also detects the back button click on browser not only page refresh.

Comment: Not working in my case.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to keep some variable before page was refreshed:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    // your logic here
});
```

If you want to load some content based on some condition:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    // your logic here
});
```

Answer (score 9):

All the code is client side, I hope you fine this helpful:

First thing there are 3 functions we will use:

```
    function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

    function getCookie(c_name) {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }

    function DeleteCookie(name) {
            document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }
```

Now we will start with the page load:

```
$(window).load(function () {
 //if IsRefresh cookie exists
 var IsRefresh = getCookie("IsRefresh");
 if (IsRefresh != null && IsRefresh != "") {
    //cookie exists then you refreshed this page(F5, reload button or right click and reload)
    //SOME CODE
    DeleteCookie("IsRefresh");
 }
 else {
    //cookie doesnt exists then you landed on this page
    //SOME CODE
    setCookie("IsRefresh", "true", 1);
 }
})
```

Comment: When I tried this it fired the test code for first load every other time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two events on client side as given below.

**1. window.onbeforeunload** (calls on Browser/tab Close & Page Load)

**2. window.onload** (calls on Page Load)

> On server Side

```
public JsonResult TestAjax( string IsRefresh)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        return result = Json("Called", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

> On Client Side

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: '/Home/TestAjax',
            data: { IsRefresh: 'Close' }
        });
    };

    window.onload = function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: '/Home/TestAjax',
            data: {IsRefresh:'Load'}
        });
    };
</script>
```

**On Browser/Tab Close:**
if user close the Browser/tab, then window.onbeforeunload will fire and IsRefresh value on server side will be "Close".

**On Refresh/Reload/F5:**
If user will refresh the page, first window.onbeforeunload will fire with IsRefresh value = "Close" and then window.onload will fire with IsRefresh value = "Load", so now you can determine at last that your page is refreshing.