# How to catch an event when tab is being reloaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Google Chrome Extension and I need to know when the tab is being reloaded or redirected to another page. `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function callback)` let's me know when the tab is being redirected simply by checking if `changeInfo.url` is not `undefined`. But how can I catch when it's being current page on active tab is being reloaded? I tried to do it with `changeInfo.status`, but that's not working, since I'm making changes to page and this event `onUpdated` event is being fired then too.

Comment: Does either of these help you ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013429/jquery-detect-page-refresh
http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: It does if I want to manage it with content scripts which is then messaging background script. But isn't there a more "direct" way?

Comment: If you have a server side you might work something over HTTP requests as like "hey I have seen a request to this page before so it must be being reloaded" but I really dont believe it will be efficient or elegant at all. Beyond that this is all I have, I am sorry... But there might be another way of course

Comment: Nothing connected with server side :).