# Is It possible to call a user defined JS function when the page refresh button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

Is It possible to call a user defined JS function when the page refresh button is clicked? I want to call a reload function, if yes is clicked I want the user to logout.
Below is my code
I used. but am getting a different confirmation pop up which reloads the page. I am nor able to call my custom function. Below is my code window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            var r=confirm("Do you want to leave page!");
            if (r)
            {
                //write redirection code
                sessLogOut();
            }
            else
           {
                //do nothing
            }
            };

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO @Jeyalakshmi, please read the [tour] before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect a page refresh using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013429/how-do-i-detect-a-page-refresh-using-jquery)

Comment: I used. but am getting a different confirmation pop up which reloads the page. I am nor able to call my custom function. Below is my code window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         var r=confirm("Do you want to leave page!");
            if (r)
            {
                //write redirection code
             sessLogOut();
            }
            else
           {
                //do nothing
            }
         };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution for you may be using this in your html:

```
<body onunload="pageUnload()">
```

and this in JS:

```
function pageUnload(){
  if(confirm("Do you want to leave page!")){
     // DO SOMETHING
  } else {
     // DO NOTHING
  }
}
```

Comment: I used. but am getting a different confirmation pop up which reloads the page. I am nor able to call my custom function. Below is my code window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         var r=confirm("Do you want to leave page!");
            if (r)
            {
                //write redirection code
             sessLogOut();
            }
            else
           {
                //do nothing
            }
         };

Comment: please mark as the right answer, if i solved your issue... ;)