# redirect to new page when the page is reloaded in django

Tags: javascript, django

I am doing a web application using django framework. In a form in my app I need to go or redirect to a new page when the page is reloaded not when the form is posted. Really appreciate the community for your answers.

app.html

```
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>
  <body>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    #somecode
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">YES</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When this page is relaoded or refreshed I need to go to a new page(my home page in views.py)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in form tag to open in new tab :
< form method="post" target="_blank">

Comment: but how it will work when the page gets reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is your form:

form.html(template name)

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    #somecode
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">YES</button>
</form>
```

you have a view from where you are rendering this template.Write this view as:

```
def viewname(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=formname(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            do_your_work
            return redirect('you another view from where you will render another template/page')
    else:
        form = formname()
    return redirect(request, 'form.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I need to go to a new page when the page is reloaded ,if I submit the page it is going to another page.

Comment: May I know, why are you trying to redirect the user on "reload" rather than submitting the form?

Comment: btw you can see these links. It might help you.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013429/how-do-i-detect-a-page-refresh-using-jquery

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: In my app if the user refresh the page the alert script get reloaded so I thought it will be best for redirecting to a page on refresh

Comment: you can stop your alert on refresh if you want.

Comment: how will do it?