# Keep scrolled position of page on reload or change page discarding previous

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've a problem when I try to switch between pages.

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
       
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
            $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
        }
    });
```

I use this script to keep the scrolled position on reload but the problem is that
when I go to another page, it takes the scroled position on the previuos one.
Is there a solution instead of storing the position not in the session but to use the url too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to a solution.

thanks to this question [How do I detect a page refresh using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013429/how-do-i-detect-a-page-refresh-using-jquery) and the answer of Uzair

I've wrote this script

```
    $(function () {
        if (sessionStorage.tempScrollTop) {
            $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.tempScrollTop);
        }
    });

    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("tempScrollTop", $(window).scrollTop());
    });

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("tempScrollTop", $(window).scrollTop());
    });
```

On same page the scrolled position is kept but once i change page it goes to the top.

Answer (score 0):

It's not beautiful, but it will work:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   sessionStorage.setItem('scroll-for-'+window.location,(this).scrollTop());
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('scroll-for-'+window.location) != "undefined") {
        $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem('scroll-for-'+window.location));
    }
});
```

Comment: It dosen't work as I want, the problem is on refresh to keep the scrolled position, but when I change page to a different one to not keep it

Comment: Do you mean another URL or another page on your URL?

Comment: another url, I was thinking that in the if I can some how use the previous url to compare with the courent one.
I saw that there is document.referrer but if you refresh the page it keeps the previouse one and not the refreshed page.

Answer (score -1):

you are looking for localStorage which persists until explicitly deleted

Comment: I think OP want's to have different scroll positions on different sub-pages