# Javascript property different on a page refresh

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect page refreshes through JS. Is there a Javascript property that's different in every page load. I was looking at window.performance but just noticed that it not available in mobile browsers.

Comment: I would have thought the entire script resetting would be noticeable...

Comment: You might want to see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699357/event-calling-before-page-unload)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this reliably since browsers do not reliably fire events after the refresh button is clicked, but it before it refreshes.

In order to do this, you need some kind of backend framework in place. Something like,

```
<img src='api.mysite.com/loadedPage.png?page=1'>
```

With the above request being recorded by your server.