# Slow page refresh in Chrome with AJAX long polling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, notifications, polling

I'm writing a notification service for my website using jQuery and AJAX for long polling, however if I try to refresh the page when the HTTP request is pending (ie normal behaviour) it's really slow, like it's waiting for the server's response (actually it is, if I stop the apache service it immediately stops loading).
How can I solve?

My JS code:

```
function getNotifications(timestamp=0) {
    $.getJSON(
        '/helper/notifications/check/'+timestamp,
        function(notification){
            if (!notification)
                return
            $("#notification").fadeIn();
            $("#notification h5").text(notification.title);
            $("#notification span").text(notification.text);
            $("#notification").attr('href', notification.action);

            getNotifications(notification.timestamp);
        }
    );
}

$(function() {
    getNotifications();
});
```

Comment: My first thought was you could try to catch the unload event that happens when a person leaves the page (related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699357/event-calling-before-page-unload#3699372) and when that happens, cancel the ajax request.

Comment: I've tried, but nothing changes. It still takes a lot to reload

Comment: So you have performed the request cancel logic already?

Comment: You need a delay in there. You are creating a DDOS on your own site. Or use websockets

Comment: That's a long polling, the request hangs up for a good while